# Pseudoswitch Statemachine

Tags: lua, switch-statement, state-machine

I'm trying to use the lua "pseudo"switch to set up a state machine but got some struggles with it.

Lets say the state-machine should detect several colour combinations and return a specific other colour. (Just an example to show the principle)

There's always a "old" state and a "new" state.

```
local state = {{},{}}
state["red"]["blue"] = function()
   stop_a_timer() 
   return "purple"
end
state["blue"]["green"] = function()
   call_a_function()
   return "cyan"
end
state["green"]["red"] = function()
   call_another_function()
   return ("yellow")
end

function state_handler(old_state, new_state) 
   if not (state[old_state][new_state]()) then
     return false
   end
end
```

So far, it's pretty simple to check for several values, but how could i check for a "false" value?

How could I set a state that is :

```
(old_state == "green") and (new_state != "blue")
```

of course

```
state["green"][(not "blue")] = function () whatever end
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invent your own notation. E.g. `"!blue"` would stand for anything other than blue:

```
state["green"]["!blue"] = function () whatever end
```

Then `state_handler` would look like:

```
function state_handler(old_state, new_state) 
  for selector, fun in pairs(state[old_state]) do
    if selector == new_state then
      fun()
    end
    if selector:find "^!" and selector ~= ("!" .. new_state) then
      fun()
    end
  end
end
```

Our notation is supported here for `new_state` only. If you want it for `old_state` too, you'll have to tweak this function.